# What is the proper way to turn a mesh into solid white?

Tags: mesh, color

I'm trying to use the grease pencil tool to try and mess with 2d animation in blender. I made a grid background but I'm running into issue with turning it pure white. Right now the background I made is grayish after applying color. Should I make a quick background image of pure white and import it? Whats the proper way of turning a mesh into a solid color?

Comment: If that's all you need, you could switch to Blender Render and use a shadeless material. In Cycles, use a simple emission shader to get close.

Answer (score 2):

pycoder's comment is correct. For future projects, you can directly adjust the background colour in the world tab.

[image]